# How to create a 2Darray grid in Python

Tags: python, arrays

A grid game draws a 6 by 4 grid with each square denoted by “x”. A character “O” can move by entering a row coordinate from 1 to 6 and column co-ordinate from 1 to 4. The character starts at array position [0,0] (Figure 1) and will move, for example, to row 0 column 1 (Figure 2) if the user enters 1, 2 for the row and column coordinates. Remember that the indices of the array both start at 0. 
    Write a pseudocode algorithm that creates a 2-D grid[row, column], drawn as shown in Figure 1.
    Prompt the user to enter a row and column value. Update the character position and draw the new grid.

```
O   x   x   x      x    O   x   x
x   x   x   x      x    x   x   x
x   x   x   x      x    x   x   x
x   x   x   x      x    x   x   x
x   x   x   x      x    x   x   x
x   x   x   x      x    x   x   x


Figure 1           Figure 2
```

Comment: Try using list of lists for 2D array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert lists in lists to create a 2D grid, a more convenient way is to use `numpy`

```py
x = [["X", "X", "X", "X"],["X", "X", "X", "X"],["X", "X", "X", "X"],["X", "X", "X", "X"],["X", "X", "X", "X"],["X", "X", "X", "X"]]
# 2d grid
print(x)

# insert a "O"
x[2][1] = "O"
print(x)

#### with numpy
import numpy as np

x2 = np.full((6,4), "X")
print(x2)

x2[2, 1] = "O"
print(x2)
```